# Length values from deflate algorithm

Tags: algorithm, inflate

I compressed the text "TestingTesting" and the hex result was: 0B 49 2D 2E C9 CC 4B 0F 81 50 00.  I can't figure out the length and distance codes.  The binary below is reversed because the [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1951.txt) says to read the bits from right to left (thanks Matthew Slattery for the help).  Here is what was parsed so far:

```
1                       BFINAL (last block)
01                      BTYPE (static)
1000 0100   132-48=  84 T
1001 0101   149-48= 101 e
1010 0011   163-48= 115 s
1010 0100   164-48= 116 t
1001 1001   153-48= 105 i
1001 1110   158-48= 110 n
1001 0111   151-48= 103 g
```

These are the remaining bits that I don't know how to parse:

```
1000 0100 0000 1000 0101 0000 0000 0
```

The final 10 bits (end of block value is x100) is the only part I can parse.  I think the length and distance values should be 7 (binary 0111) since the length of "Testing" is 7 letters, and it gets copied 7 characters after the current position, but I can't figure out how its representing this in the remaining bits.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you give the code table? (including the len0 and len1 codes)
Or alternatively, which choice for "static tree" did you make?

Comment: The table is in section 3.2.5 [here](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1951#page-12)

Comment: Alright well I had to check, it happens often enough that some other static huffman tree is used (unfortunately). 10000100 is an other T, 0000100 = len=6 00101 = dist=5 and then things go wrong

Comment: Thanks, I have no idea how I missed the other T or why it wasn't recognized as part of the pattern.  This at least sheds more light on what's happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The distance *code* is 5, but a distance code of 5 is followed by one "extra bit" to indicate an actual distance of either 7 or 8.  (See the second table in paragraph 3.2.5 of the RFC.)

The complete decoding of the data is:

```
1          BFINAL
01         BTYPE=static
10000100  'T'
10010101  'e'
10100011  's'
10100100  't'
10011001  'i'
10011110  'n'
10010111  'g'
10000100  another 'T'
0000100   literal/length code 260 = length 6
00101     distance code 5
0         extra bit  => the distance is 7
0000000   literal/length code 256 = end of block
```

Comment: nice, I forgot about the extra bit, makes sense now